change format of coordinates extracted from Geom
I'm using the following code to reverse lookup address in a dataframe:
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="osm")
    geolocator.reverse("54.954094, -1.60510")

My coordinates were extracted from Line Geom, such as:
LINESTRING Z (-0.046635 51.6484886 0, -0.04603...

I use the following code to extract the coordindate and do the reverse
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
def get_address(coor):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="osm")
    x=geolocator.reverse(coor)
    return x[0].split(',')[:3]

For reason I don't know, one of the Linestring showed coordinates with scientific notation:
 LINESTRING Z (1.16e-6 51.6484886 0, -0.04603...

rather than 0.00000116, the geolocator.reverse function doesn't like it, throw me an error.
I tried to convert it, however as it's a string rather than actual scientific format, I'm stuck.
Hope smart people on stackoverflow can help me please?
Either a way to get linestring Z without scientific notation or a better way to extract the coordindates out that can change the format to float. Or whatever other options available to get the address of a Geo Line.
Thank you so much

You need to process your coordinates string first, with the use of python's float() function you can convert the scientific format to decimal.
Something like :
linestring = "LINESTRING Z (1.16e-6 51.6484886 0, -0.046635 51.6484886 0)"

raw_coordinates = linestring.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
points = raw_coordinates.split(',')

converted_coordinates = []

for point in points:
    x, y, z = point.strip().split()
    latitude = "{:.8f}".format(float(y))
    longitude = "{:.8f}".format(float(x))
    converted_coordinates .append(f"{latitude}, {longitude}")

Then you can use converted_coordinates for reverse geocoding.
